# Screen and audio capture software

Tags: windows, screen-recording, audio-recording

Please recommend software to capture *both* screen video and audio.

Audio capturing is absolutely required.

I mean capture not audio from microphone, but audio, generated by the computer itself. So, I need to capture both generated audio and video.

Solutions should work out of the box, no special buggy drivers acceptable.

I have tested [Debut Professional](http://www.nchsoftware.com/capture/) v 2.25 and [Open Broadcaster](https://obsproject.com/) v 0.675 b.
Both are carefully avoiding to capture audio.

I need this for Windows, and the price should be just reasonable.

Comment: You tried OBS Classic or OBS Studio? OBS Studio [should allow capturing 4 audio streams](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-high-quality-recording-and-multiple-audio-tracks.221/)

Comment: @Thomas according to this screenshot https://www.helping-squad.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/OBS-Studio_Audio_Settings.png I suspect it records these 4 streams from external. I need to record whatever computer generates.

Comment: A compliant NVIDIA card will be able to use ShadowPlay, which I have been very happy with. Does not work only for games either, works with other applications. Can stream as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any program (Windows Sound Recorder, [Sound booth](https://www.adobe.com/sea/products/soundbooth/), [audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/) etc) that records audio can record sound from windows, you just need to know how to set windows up.

You are not really looking for another screen recorder that will work, but rather how to get  to record audio.
I use [HyperCam](http://www.hyperionics.com/) and [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/), both free, they record video *and* audio.

I when through this struggle, and tried MANY different screen recorders. None of them will recorded system audio "out of the box."

My answer came from an article like [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/) (sadly I can not find the original article I learned this from).

It is very easy to do, once you know how, just three steps:

1. Right click on the sound icon in the system tray, choose *"Recording Devices"*.
   [image: windows sound dialogue]
2. (Here is the hidden part) Right click in a empty part of the list, choose *"Show Disabled Devices"*. Now magically a new device *"Stereo Mix"* shows up. That is the device that will let programs record sound.
   [image: Windows sound settings]
3. Now in your recording software open up the audio options and set it to use *"Stereo Mix"*.
   This is a screen shot from HyperCam, but every software will have similar settings.
   [image: HyperCam audio recording settings]

Comment: Incredible! I knew it was possible to capture sound in old versions of Windows, but when this feature is gone, I didn't knew it can be returned!!!

Comment: What do I need to make step 2 work? I have checked disabled and disconnected devices but I don't see a Stereo Mix device. It seems to depend on the drivers. (Windows 7 x64 SP1, Updates installed)

Comment: @ThomasWeller bummer. That is a semi common problem with win7 and up. First thing they always say is to update (or down grade?!) the audio drivers. [Here](http://iamdotnetcrazy.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-find-stereo-mix-on-windows-7-how.html) is a post that looks rather helpful. Thankfully I have had stereo mix work on my computers, so I have not had to try to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Try Joyoshare Screen Recorder or Camtasia. I have them on my computer. Camtasia even supports separate video and audio tracks.

Comment: Welcome Allison!  Thank you for your answer.  Can you add links to both of your recommendations in your answer?  Also, can you confirm that neither requires a special driver, per the OP's requirement?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"Reasonable" is not really a quantifiable size, so I have no idea how to satisfy that requirement, but the professional solution is generally [xsplit](https://www.xsplit.com/#home). Plenty of twitch and youtube-channels use this software to capture screen and audio-data for local editing.

Comment: I opened XSplit Gamecaster and it asked to "switch to any game or open console window". Since I wish to capture entire desctop, I did nothing. Then it asked to press Ctrl-TAB. Once I pressed it, it showed a warning https://i.imgur.com/WuTv3ir.jpg  Looks like it is able to capture only OpenGL or DirectX games. Should I try something else?

Comment: yeah, you want Broadcaster, not gamecaster: [capture desktop](https://www.xsplit.com/broadcaster/faq/getting-started/how-do-i-capture-my-desktop-or-a-window) How to set up audio is in that faq I linked as well.